# Pandas: get first value after Index (without depending on Index type)

Tags: python, pandas

Let us say we have a `DatetimeIndex`:

```py
months = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=12, freq='M')
months
=> DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-31', '2000-02-29', '2000-03-31', '2000-04-30',
               '2000-05-31', '2000-06-30', '2000-07-31', '2000-08-31',
               '2000-09-30', '2000-10-31', '2000-11-30', '2000-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

we could get the first value after/off index with:

```py
months.shift(1)[-1]
=> Timestamp('2001-01-31 00:00:00', freq='M')
```

And if we have a `RangeIndex`:

```py
range_index = pd.RangeIndex(1, 100, step=10)
range_index
=> RangeIndex(start=1, stop=100, step=10)
```

we could:

```py
range_index[-1] + range_index.step
=> 101
```

Now I am looking for a function that does not depend on the index type. We could check the index type to decide how to do it, e.g.:

```py
def first_value_off_index(index):
    if isinstance(index, pd.RangeIndex):
        return index[-1] + index.step
    if isinstance(index, pd.DatetimeIndex):
        return index.shift(1)[-1]
    raise RuntimeError('Unsupported index type')
```

But this is neither very general, nor very satisfactory to have to do some type-based branching. My question: is there a native pandas way to do the same? And if not, a way that does not depend on type branching.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have only these 2 options (which in my mind is the case) i.e. that it's either numeric, or datetime:

```py
def first_value_off_index(index):
    try:
        return pd.date_range(index[-1], periods=2, freq=index.freq)[-1]
    except:
        return index[-1]+index.step
```

Comment: Is not there a limit, in the sense that, when taking `months = pd.date_range('2000-03-01', periods=12, freq='M')` and applying the delta approach, you would get Timestamp('2001-03-28 00:00:00', freq='M') rather than 04-01.

Comment: Yes, I guess we are trading explicit type branching for an implicit type assumption (rescuing AttributeError and falling back to the range version). I was hoping for something more polymorphic. It is just too bad, that for a RangeIndex, `range_index + range_index.step`, is not aliased as `range_index.shift(1)` or something along those lines, that would treat steps and freqs similarly. We would have a fully polymorphic way of defining the function.